# How can I make an ngFor index variable visible to the rest of the template?

Tags: angular

I have two ngFor directives, the first shown here has an index indx:

```
      <li  *ngFor="let navItem of ingredients.navItems; index as indx"
        class="nav-item"
        role="presentation"
      >
        <a
          class="nav-link ingredients"
          [ngClass]="{ active: indx === 0 }"
          role="tab"
          data-bs-toggle="tab"
          href="{{ navItem.href }}"
        >
          <strong>{{ navItem.title }}</strong>
        </a>
      </li>
```

I want to use indx of the previous ngFor directive in the ngClass of another ngFor directive later in the template as shown here but indx is out of scope so cannot be used as shown: How can I make indx a template variable?

```
             <li *ngFor="let navItem of tabcontent.navItems"
              class="nav-item"
              role="presentation"
            >
             <a
                class="nav-link ingredients"
                [ngClass]="{ active: indx === 0 }"
                role="tab"
                data-bs-toggle="tab"
                href="{{ navItem.href }}"
                ><strong>{{ navItem.name }}</strong></a
              >
            </li>
```

Comment: This is not possible and doesn't make much sense. Those are 2 different scopes.

Comment: @Matthew Are you familiar with a template variable. A template variable in one scope is visible throughout the page irrespective of scope. It is the same concept I am trying to apply to my problem. If the concept of template variable makes sense, why doesn't my question?

Comment: An index in a for loop only makes sense in the said for loop, a it changes for every iteration.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

You're probably looking for [`RouterLink`](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink) and [`RouterLinkActive`](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive).

This will allow you to have a special styling for the current page.

Answer (score 0):

you can assign the index value to template variable but please remember it will change on each iteration

<span #tempRefVariable=indx>